# Getting the dtype of a result array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to preallocate memory for the output of an array operation, and I need to know what dtype to make it.  Below I have a function that does what I want it to do, but is terribly ugly.

```
import numpy as np

def array_operation(arr1, arr2):
    out_shape = arr1.shape
    # Get the dtype of the output, these lines are the ones I want to replace.
    index1 = ([0],) * arr1.ndim
    index2 = ([0],) * arr2.ndim
    tmp_arr = arr1[index1] * arr2[index2]
    out_dtype = tmp_arr.dtype
    # All so I can do the following.
    out_arr = np.empty(out_shape, out_dtype)
```

The above is pretty ugly.  Does numpy have a function that does this?

Comment: Are you interested in the dtype after multiplication only?

Comment: @unutbu, Can you explain why you ask?

Comment: @Mike Graham: On could enumerate all the basic dtypes, compute the resultant types of all pairs after multiplication, and store result in a dictionary. This wouldn't work for more complicated dtypes though...

Comment: @ubutbu, Can you provide an example of a time another operation gives a different resulting original-dtypes-dependent dtype for multiplication and another operation?

Comment: @Mike Graham: I was thinking more about arbitrary (numpy) function calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`numpy.result_type`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html).

(As an aside, do you realize that you can access all multi-dimensional arrays as 1d arrays? You don't need to access `x[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` -- you can access `x.flat[0]`.)

Comment: What numpy version are you using?  1.3.0 doesn't seem to have a `result_type` function.

Comment: To your aside: `x[0]` would 'full slice' all other axes except the first.  That could be a lot of extra multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

For those using numpy version < 1.6, you could use:

```
def result_type(arr1, arr2):
    x1 = arr1.flat[0]
    x2 = arr2.flat[0]
    return (x1 * x2).dtype

def array_operation(arr1, arr2):
    return np.empty(arr1.shape, result_type(arr1, arr2))
```

This isn't very different from the code you posted, though I think `arr1.flat[0]` is a slight improvement over `index1 = ([0],) * arr1.ndim; arr1[index1]`.

For numpy version >= 1.6, use Mike Graham's answer, [np.result_type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html)