# Determine widening conversion of NumPy types

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have a library based on NumPy with a few classes that overload the arithmetic operations.  The internals are a little hairy due to a significant amount of error checking, but I've run across a serious problem with how I'm doing it.

The idea behind the library is to make it very easy and intuitive to use with minimal syntax and effort by the programmer.  As such, I want it to be easy to combine arrays of different data types and simply convert the narrower data type to the wider case.

For example, if I have two arrays, one with dtype `float64` and the other with dtype `complex128`, when adding them together I would like to convert the `float64` to `complex128`, but if it's `float64` and `complex192`, I want to convert to that instead.  However, if it was a combination of `float64` and `complex64`, there isn't a valid conversion between the two without losing precision of the `float64`, so I would want to convert both to `complex128`.

I immediately saw the problem that I would have to look for each combination of types and determine their narrowest common widened type (think least common multiple) if I wanted my library to be fully robust.  I *don't* want to convert everything to the widest type possible, since that becomes memory inefficient very quickly, and I often have very large arrays stored in memory.

**Is there a good way to determine the narrowest common widened type between two NumPy types?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the dtype of a result array in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285612/getting-the-dtype-of-a-result-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@amaurea has the right idea; in fact, functions already exist in numpy for this.
Take a look at [result_type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) and [promote_types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html).

Comment: Thanks, this solution required only a 3 line change to my current code to fix the bug, it is exactly what I needed and is definitely the idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think numpy already does this internally, so how about just asking numpy?

```
(zeros([],dtype=float64)+zeros([],dtype=complex64)).dtype
=> dtype('complex128')

(zeros([],dtype=float32)+zeros([],dtype=complex64)).dtype
=> dtype('complex64')
```

You could generalize this into a function:

```
def common_dtype(dtypes):
    return np.sum([np.zeros([],dtype=d) for d in dtypes]).dtype
```

Comment: I like the `common_dtype` function, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html and
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That looks to be the preferred way to do this.  Even though amaurea's solution would work, I have to admit that these two functions are better suited.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.